# Condições PHP if elseif

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em php e quero determinar se determinada palavra vai receber a letra "a" ou a letra "o".

Estava fazendo com `if` e `elseif`, mas não sei porque não está dando certo.

Vou colocar um exemplo que fiz para demonstrar meu problema, esse não é o código da minha aplicação, mas é um exemplo que explica bem meu problema.

```
$type = "";
$texto1 = "carr";
$texto2 = "cas";

if($texto1){
$type = "o";
}elseif($texto2){
$type = "a";
}
echo $texto1.$type . '<br>';
echo $texto1.$type;
```

Comment: `if ($texto1)`, o que você espera verificar com isso?

Comment: ola, vc nao pode usar $texto1 como condição booleana, vc teria que fazer algo assim:

if($texto1 == "carr")

string comparando string
int comparando int

Answer (score 0):

O construtor `if` tem o retorno do tipo `booleano`, ou seja, testa se a condição é `verdadeira` ou `falsa`. Desse modo, seu código está testando se a variável `$texto1` é verdadeira, e como ela não está vazia, o retorno sempre sera `true`.

Dê uma olhada nas estruturas de controle do `php`:

https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.control-structures.php